# How to install the Ruby-2.7.3 version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins, rubygems

Getting this error:-
jenkins_api_client-1.5.3 requires ruby version ~> 2.1, which is incompatible
with the current version, ruby 3.1.2p20

I have tried all the possibilities from this documentation to install version 2.7.3 https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ruby-on-ubuntu-20-04/

But it is not installing the ruby showing the warning as "ruby-2.7.3 is past its end of life and is now unsupported" and not proceeding further

Comment: Why are you not rather updating `jenkins_api_client` ? Is it a legacy app ? Because `~> 2.1` means that 2.7.3 will probably not work either, please read here about the meaning of `~>` : https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic-version-constraint Also I recommend you to use RVM (Ruby version manager) to install your rubies. So much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install), per [the official documentation on Ruby installation](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/).

Nb, is your OS the same as the one in the link provided, i.e., ubuntu version 20.04?

Edit: Using a more recent version (e.g., 2.0) of the `jenkins_api_client` is also definitely resolving.

Comment: ubuntu version is  22.04